# Which are the major truths of paradigms on which the whole body of chemistry is built?

Tags: theoretical-chemistry

For example, as evolutionary theory is fo biology or the existence of numbers for math, the existence of an independent reality for physics, etc.

Comment: The periodic table

Answer (score 0):

Well the most important driving force I see in chemistry is for atoms and molecules to be most stable when the atoms have a noble gas electronic configeration. Many reactions will occur to try to reduce the energy of the atoms and molecules by gaining / losing or rearranging electrons to bring as many atoms as close as possible to a noble gas configeration.

Another important driving force is to reduce or avoid the mechanical strain in a molecule (Steric effects)

There are effects in pi systems such as aromaticness (4n + 2 pi electrons in rings)

There are entropy effects, by increasing the entropy of a system then an endothermic reaction can be made to occur. For example the dissolution of ammonium nitrate in water occurs with ease but this is an endothermic process.